# jQuery IE 9 crash when replacing "tbody" value after clicking on an element inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have an application in which I'd like a user action - checking on a checkbox - to cause a chain of actions that results, among other things, in the table in which the checkbox appears to be rewritten. This works fine in all browsers I've tested except IE 9.

I've reproduced the behavior in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vM7Bu/3/

but essentially the idea is

```
$('tbody#mytablebody').empty();
for (var i in something) {
  $('tbody#mytablebody').append(makeNewRow(i));
}
```

Even in IE 9 this works fine unless it's triggered by a user clicking on something inside the current body of the table. In that case, IE goes into some kind of infinite loop.

Is this a known issue in IE 9? What workarounds might be available?

**EDIT**: I narrowed the problem down a little - it's not so much the sequence of events triggered from a click, but rather the fact that we're attempting to replace the `innerHTML` of a `tbody` (I think) when an element inside it has focus. Finding that element and `blur`ing it seems to have helped somewhat. More investigation required.

Comment: I'd report this to Microsoft, if it is indeed an infinite loop. A denial of service attack with no way to get a malicious payload into the system is still something to be concerned about: http://www.microsoft.com/security/msrc/report.aspx

Comment: Well, it sure looks like one. I haven't tried digging into the jQuery code to introduce debug statements, or trying it on my own without jQuery yet...

Comment: try it without jquery, reduce it to the absolute smallest example case you can. If it still occurs with this minimal test, then it's a bug, and should be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, though I still have not managed to reproduce it without the use of jQuery, the issue is that in IE 9 you cannot remove certain kinds of elements from the DOM if those elements still have keyboard focus. That seems to be the rule. I will report it to MS if I can actually reproduce it in standalone code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible work-around.  In the click handler, call setTimeout(xxx, 0); and do your work from the setTimeout function.  If IE is crashing because you are removing parts of the table that you're in the middle of a click handler for, then the setTimeout will get you out of the click handler before remove that part of the table.

Pseudo-code:

```
$("#whatever").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('tbody#mytablebody').empty();
        for (var i in something) {
            $('tbody#mytablebody').append(makeNewRow(i));
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: I'll try that. In my real application, the scary thing is it's not a click handler. It's just the result of a trigger that in turn happens as a result of a series of actions (including two AJAX roundtrips) triggered by a click.

Comment: If it's a generic table modification bug and not the result of doing the modification from an event handler inside the table itself, then you may need to find a different way to modify the table, perhaps creating a whole new table and remove this one entirely or just rewriting row contents rather than destroying and recreating rows.